# In AngularJS how can I create a new ngController dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to create new `ngController`s on the fly, is this possible? I'm not writing it into the template with a `ngRepeat` or anything, since the user might never create an instance of a certain `ngController`.

Here's an example of my current template:

```
<div ng-controller="ViewUsers">
   <div class="viewUsersList">
      <table>
         <tr class="userRow" ng-click="viewUser(user.user_id)" ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td>{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}
                <br />{{user.phone}}
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
 </div>
```

So far it works great. When the user clicks a `.userRow` it calls `viewUser(ID)`. The problem is here:

I want to create a new block of code like this:

```
<div ng-controller="UserDetail">
   {{first_name}}
</div>
```

And append this to the DOM.

So if they click on `Bobby` and `Sally`, two `UserDetail` controller objects would be added to the DOM and work accordingly. (Ideally, I'd like to pass in the data-bound `user` model, but that's for later).

I tried a ghetto version in JSBin, but I'd rather not use JQuery if possible:

http://jsbin.com/EdOteTav/2/edit

Can anyone shine some light on this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the code little bit and use directive instead of controller. See this simple and quick example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kura/DaSqj/3/).

The directive would handle the click events and display whatever you want to display on the DOM. You can get the full user object from `scope.user` inside the directive.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I ended up doing an `ng-repeat="user in users"` with a `ng-controller="UserDetail"` instead of the `repeat`. Ideally, I would have liked some more ecapsulation (not having `UserDetail` being a child of `ViewUsers`, but this'll have to do for now)